# barplot changes with pandas in python

Tags: pandas, bar-chart

[image]

How can I edit the chart?
Change the size,color,labels and etc?
Thank you

and by the wat how im deleting this line above the chart <axessubplpt...

Answer (score 1):

`df.plot.bar` returns the `Axes` object:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(...)
```

You can change the properties of this object, e.g.

```
ax.legend()
```

When you equate `ax = df...`, this text `<AxesSubplot:xlabel...>` will not be shown.